# Low screen resolution on android emulator, visual studio, xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

[image]

As you can see here^ the resolution of my android emulator is stuffed up. Does anyone know how to change the resolution?

Comment: I'm pretty late to the party, but did you fix this issue?

Comment: This whole app turned into a flop and was redone in XCode, I cant remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not an "answer" to the question, I would really recommend using another emulator.

Windows has a few options, but the two most common are the Visual Studio Android Emulator from Microsoft:

Website: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

There are some [docs from Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/) that can help.

This is the emulator I use on Windows. It uses Hyper-V and typically works well. If you have not installed Hyper-V, you can [do so using the Add/Remove Windows Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install).

Another option is to use the hardware-accelerated emulators provided by Google. By default, the "slow" emulator are installed, but there are better ones. The thing to note is that this cannot run side-by-side with Hyper-V.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

I would suggest using the Microsoft emulators if you can, as you don't need to configure much. If you are using virtual machines - such as VirtualBox or VMWare, then you probably have disabled Hyper-V. In this case, use the Google emulators.

Just for reference, there are other emulators, such as Genymotion: https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: I dont want Hyper-V installed as I need to be able to use Virtual Box as well which is impossible to use in conjunction. I might try to the google one, thanks for the heads up. I have Genymotion installed, was just unable to get it to work so I might try again with that.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the device from a device definition in the AVD manager:

Once you click OK at the bottom of the form, it will ask you for the scaling.

Adjust your Desktop to its correct size and make sure you are viewing the device to the correct scale.